# does c++ singleton create new instance every time?

Tags: c++, singleton

C++ singleton code looks like this:

```
MyClass& MyClass::getInstance(){
    static MyClass instance;
    return instance;
}
```

Looking specifically at `static MyClass instance;`

Is a new `instance` created each time getInstance is called?

EDIT

I understand that static members are one-per-class. But doesn’t `static MyClass instance` re-declare (and therefore re-create) the “single” instance `instance` each time `getInstance()` is called?

Comment: No. That's what the `static` means: There's a single instance `instance` which is shared across invocations of `getInstance`. As you might suspect, it would not really be any sort of "singleton" if there were a bunch of different instances of it.

Comment: Read about this: [http://laristra.github.io/flecsi/src/developer-guide/patterns/meyers_singleton.html](http://laristra.github.io/flecsi/src/developer-guide/patterns/meyers_singleton.html)

Comment: A static member of a function is created only once the first time the function is called.

Comment: No.   A static variable, by definition, is only created once and then persists for as long as the program is running.    A static variable at function scope, like `instance`, is constructed exactly once at (or before) the containing block is entered for the first time.   In your case, every call of `getInstance()` returns a reference to the same object.

Comment: But doesn’t `static MyClass instance` re-declare (and therefore re-create) the single static variable called `instance` each time `getInstance()` is called?

Comment: Effectively replacing it ^ each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `MyClass` member variable is declared as `static` and you are returning a reference to it, not a copy. Static member variables are not created per-object like normal member variables; rather, there is one instance of the variable accessible from all objects of the class.

[See here.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static)

Comment: Thanks. I understand that static member are one-per-class (and not instance related). 

But my question is - doesn’t `static MyClass instance` re-declare (and therefore re-create) the single`instance` each time `getInstance()` is called? Effectively replacing it each time.

Comment: i still think you arent understanding what static means. static variable initialization only happens once.

Comment: thanks. I hope you understand where I'm coming from.
Are you saying that the first time we call `static MyClass instance`, an new `instance` will be created. Each subsequent time, there will be a lookup to see if `instance` exists and it will be returned (not newly created)?

Comment: yes. that is how it works. Test it out if you want to. In the constructor of `MyClass` in the code above, put in code that prints something to the console. That way you can see it constructs a MyClass once and never does again.